# ROS Answers SE migration: URDF wrong

Tags: urdf, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i input the command"rosrun urdf_parser check_urdf my_robot.urdf "to the new terminal.error emerge as below:
[ERROR] [1388809948.900513147]: Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114766/urdf-wrong/) by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check_urdf should provide you some details that suggests what was wrong with your URDF file that caused the failure.  What do you see after running check_urdf?

---

Originally posted by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) with karma: 159 on 2014-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0